# Sorting multiple columns based on 2 columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with multiple alphabetical values which I want to sort. For instance

```
ii     A.1     A.2      B.1     B.2
1      Xy      foo      Ly      bar
2      Ab      bar      Ko      foo
```

So I'd like to sort each row according to `A.1` and `B.1`, and reorder `A.2` and `B.2` according to that order. This would become:

```
ii     s1      s2       b1      b2
1      Ly      bar      Xy      foo
2      Ab      bar      Ko      foo
```

I am trying to use `df.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values())`. However, I am having problems changing the order of the additional columns (`A.2` and `B.2`). How would you do this?

**Edit:** **to clarify, I need to sort `A.2 B.2` according to the order specified by the *sorted* `A.1` and `B.1`. For instance:**

```
ii     A.1     A.2      B.1     B.2
1      Xy      mat      Ly      bar
2      Ab      zul      Ko      foo #shouldn't change
```

becomes:

```
ii     A.1     A.2      B.1     B.2
1      Ly      bar      Xy      mat
2      Ab      zul      Ko      foo #notice, this is unchanged because A.1 B.1 are already sorted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe need [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) for positions by sorted array and then get values by indices in arr and assign back:

```
arr = df[['A.1', 'B.1']].values.argsort()
print (arr)
[[1 0]
 [0 1]]

df[['A.1', 'B.1']] = df[['A.1', 'B.1']].values[np.arange(len(arr))[:,None], arr]
df[['A.2', 'B.2']] = df[['A.2', 'B.2']].values[np.arange(len(arr))[:,None], arr]
print (df)
   ii A.1  A.2 B.1  B.2
0   1  Ly  bar  Xy  foo
1   2  Ab  bar  Ko  foo
```

With new data:

```
print (df)
   ii A.1  A.2 B.1  B.2
0   1  Ly  bar  Xy  mat
1   2  Ab  zul  Ko  foo
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it was kind of you to not only answer but also edit your answer with the new data :)